# CSS margin with multiple types

Tags: css

Sorry for this dumb question but
I found in a piece of code that looks like

```
margin-left: 150px;
margin-left: 8%;
margin-left: 7vw;
```

Can you please explain me who this work? which will be used?
Also can't we write something like:

```
margin-left: 150px, 8%, 7vm;
```

I think of this as a short version or something?
**EDIT** I was asking only about margin-left not about all the properties of margin :)

Comment: `margin-left: 7vw;` will be implemented since it is in the last line of the css code.  on the other hand `margin-left: 150px, 8%, 7vm;` is not a valid css code.

Comment: @GvM thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write this way:

```
 margin-left: 150px;
 margin-left: 8%;
 margin-left: 7vw;
```

only `margin-left: 7vw;` will be accepted because it will override `margin-left: 150px;` and `margin-left: 8%;` , `margin-left`, `margin-right` , `margin-top` , `margin-bottom` only accept a single value.

You could use shorthand for margin like:

`margin: margin-top margin-right margin-bottom margin-left`

example:

`margin: 10px 15px 20px 5px;`

So in this shorthand the last one `5px` will set as `margin left` ,

There are two more ways for writing shorthand:

2 values:

`margin: (margin-top + margin-bottom) (margin-left + margin-right)`

example:

`margin: 10px 20px`

3 values:
`margin: (margin-top) (margin-left + margin-right) (margin-bottom)`

example:

`margin: 10px auto 20px`

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer I know they over write some how but I did not understand why the UI developer done that I thought this is a  rule for IE, ff or chrome. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Each next occurrence of CSS rule overwrites previous, so in this example the last one rule will be used. Your shorter form is also invalid. In single line you could define margins for each side:

```
margin: 10px 5px 2px 8px;
```

It gives you 10px top margin, 5px right margin, 2px bottom and 8px left margin.